# How to check the health status of the whole TiDB cluster?

Tags: distributed-database, tidb, tidb-pd

I've deployed the TiDB cluster for a test. I want to check whether the instances have all been started successfully, but I do not have a command line cluster management tool. In this case, how to check the health status of the TiDB cluster?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the general status of the cluster using the [pd-ctl](https://github.com/pingcap/pd/tree/master/pdctl) tool. For the detailed cluster status, you need to use the monitor to confirm.